# How to return an image with jQuery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, special-characters

```
var txtimg = new Image(); //img holder
    $(txtimg).load(function () {
        $("#div").append(this);
    }).error(function () {
        // notify the user that the image could not be loaded
        alert('error loading text');
    }).attr('src', webroot + '?drawtxt='+text.content);
```

The above code loads an image using jQuery load. It works when text.content are normal characters. However, the image won't load when text.content contains special characters which are not permitted in the URL, such as '&' character, even encoded as '%26'.

Therefore, I'm looking for a way to send some data using ajax that permits the use of special characters, and at the same time is able to return the image as well.

If I use $.ajax(), can the return value contains the binary image stream? If no, what are other ways that can do an ajax call with special characters and return an image at the same time?

Comment: why not store the images in amazon or something(instead of the db) then store the urls? isn't that easier?

Answer (score 0):

Try `escape()` http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm or `javascript urlencode()` http://phpjs.org/functions/urlencode:573

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried both(and retried), it converts '&' to '%26' but it's still not being treated as a string.

Comment: one thing I see here is that
`webroot + '?drawtxt='+text.content` has both + and . Usually + is used to append strings in JS, but . is append function in php

Comment: the dot is JS Dot Notation for objects. Nothing wrong there as I have tested with alert().